# C# C++ Interop program can not load assembly in IDE, but works when directly launching

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2012, interop

My C# program is importing some functions from a c++ dll. The program crashes when i launch it from the Visual Studio IDE and gives an error "Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies". I have the .dll referenced. It launches fine from the binary.

Weirdly enough, it launches just fine from the IDE if I enable native code debugging in the project properties.

Comment: do you have __declspec(dllexport) before your functions

Comment: I do, everything worked fine prior to me reorganizing my project structure. now it only works with native debugging enabled